# Delete one partition

Tags: gparted, ubuntu-mate

I have 2 different Ubuntu Mate installations on /dev/sda.

I want to delete /dev/sda1 and reclaim that space while leaving the other Ubuntu Mate installation intact. I do not want to have to re-install of Ubuntu Mate on remaining single partition.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Is this a dual boot system with another drive with Windows? Does this system use old BIOS or new UEFI?

Comment: This is dual boot to either 18.04 or 20.04. BIOS is about 4 years old. @user68186

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, but it would be hard to guide you through all the steps, because it depends on which partition contains the grub, you will most likely have to change your fstab. Since i would recomend you to backup your data any ways you're better off reinstalling the system.

Comment: Re-installing means a boatload of work. I will keep investigating.